# XML unbound error for custom layout

Tags: android, xml

I am using the following library: https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress

I added it to gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
}
```

I added it to my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/bg_color" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/minutes20"
                android:textColor="@color/main_color"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/health_1"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress
                    android:id="@+id/progressbar_1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    custom:circle_progress="20"/>
```

I am getting an error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

I think I somehow missed to define the namespace?

Comment: Add this line to your xml `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missed

```
 xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

add in `root layout XML`

For reference [take a look any demo file](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress/blob/master/example/src/main/res/layout/activity_my.xml)

Comment: should I add in frame layout this?

Comment: @tobias add in `root layout`. check my reference link

Comment: works like a charm. I had experimented with this line of code but did not recognize that the "custom" is what I need. Thx